# Angular4 - Can't bind to 'vgHls' since it isn't a known property of 'video'.

Tags: angular, video-streaming, html5-video

The code that i use is angular4,
I want to show the video stream width videogular2 plugin,but the error:

`Template parse errors:Can't bind to 'vgHls' since it isn't a known property of 'video'.`

app.component.html

```
<vg-player>
  <video #myMedia
     [vgHls]="'http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.m3u8'"
     (onGetBitrates)="hlsBitrates = $event"
     id="my-video"
     type="video/mp4"
     controls>
  </video>
</vg-player>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To use hls video streams in your videogular player you need to import the required modules

Import definition:

```
...
import { VgStreamingModule } from 'videogular2/streaming';

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
        ...
        VgStreamingModule
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a library, it's good practice to tell which library it is, and provide a link to it.

This issue comes from the fact that Angular has no knowledge about the `vgHls` attribute, because it's neither part of the framework, or HTML standards.

To resolve this issue, you will need to

1. Import the library and its definition into your project,
2. Import the library's module into your component's module.

Once the module is imported, all will work fine.

### EDIT

[According to the documentation](https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/docs/getting-started/), your module should look like this :

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [SingleMediaPlayer],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        VgCoreModule,
        VgControlsModule,
        VgOverlayPlayModule,
        VgBufferingModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [SingleMediaPlayer]
})
```

Comment: Thank you,the library i use is
[link](https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/docs/modules/streaming/vg-hls/)https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/docs/modules/streaming/vg-hls/

Comment: Then you will need to provide an [mcve] so that we can see the issue and resolve it. I recommend https://stackblitz.io